# Are Static Websites (HTML & CSS) Hack-Proof?

Tags: html, css, static

If a website uses HTML & CSS only without any server side language, does it make it Hack-Proof?
Thank you

Comment: This question is already answered on Security Stackexchange: [Attack surface for a site that hosts only static content HTML and images?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61556/attack-surface-for-a-site-that-hosts-only-static-content-html-and-images/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is ever really "hack-proof" when you consider the multitude of attack vectors.

Whilst a purely static website may not be susceptible to SQL injection or WordPress script-kiddie attacks, there's still the possibility of an attacker getting server access or even just FTP access. This can be mitigated by disabling any cleartext access (i.e. use SSH/SFTP in place of telnet & FTP) and good user/password management, but never assume you're totally hack-proof as there's just no such thing.

Comment: Obviously there are more attack vectors than those I've mentioned, but I don't think this answer is the place to start listing every way a website can be "hacked".

Comment: Other possible attack vectors:  Cross-site-scripting against JavaScript, DNS poisoning, man in the middle attacks and eavesdropping.

Comment: Even programming environments can be vulnerable even if no code exists on the site. It has been a while, however, at one point PHP and Java environments could be hacked. There are also reflection attacks, proxy attacks, etc.

Comment: Or bugs in the web server

Comment: Thank you everyone, for your helpful input. my next step would be to find out how or what to do to secure those flaws you all mentioned for my static site. like making a better password for example.

Comment: Complex passwords for your site should be considered, too. Change your passwords regularly and don't use any password that you use on another site.